# Is it possible to install multiple instances of node.js with the windows .msi?

Tags: node.js

I've tried to install multiple versions of node.js using the .MSI installer but it seems that the second version uninstall the previous one.

Comment: `it seems that the second version uninstall the previous one` -- That's a pretty good clue.

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/visionmedia/n, it installs and switches between node versions.

Answer (score 3):

I found this on github and solved my problem ...

https://github.com/marcelklehr/nodist

Answer (score 1):

You could install multiple copies, but you'd first need to rename the old binaries. Although at this point I'd suggest just downloading the latest binary and place it inside the same directory (renaming what you need).

Not sure how this will affect NPM as it will use what ever binary is node.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [NVM for Windows](http://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows). It comes with an installer and super-easy commands.

[image]

Comment: NVM for Windows really sucked to me. It looks as if everything is fine but as soon as I started using npm and/or closed the CMD window and open a new one...it said that the node version I had installed 2 minutes ago, was NOT installed. I strongly recommend using [nvmw](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw), it's much much simpler and more effective. (I had no relationship with nvmw, btw)

Comment: @Jonathan - Sorry to hear NVM for Windows isn't working out for you. I can't say I've had those issues. Did you try posting an issue on the Github page? I can absolutely guarantee the author (me) would respond.

Comment: @Corey I had 0.10.28 installed, then installed NVM then v4.3.1 with the executable from their website. Now obviously NVM doesn't see this version, how do I handle this?

Comment: Hi Corey, does NVM for Windows support Win7 Enterprise?

Comment: @stt106 - Officially, no. Unofficially.... most people can get it working on a stock build of the OS.

Answer (score 1):

As I commented on @Corey's answer, I tried NVM for Windows and it was really BAD. **I strongly recommend using [nvmw](https://github.com/hakobera/nvmw)**: it's very very simple, it has the same syntax as Linux's nvm (though reduced functionality) and it just works.

**IMPORTANT NOTE: Run every single command from a shell prompt with Admin privileges! If you don't, you will run into lots of weird errors!!**